# Google Stack Driver Dashboard legend (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

First, I am using Google StackDriver (Google Cloud Plataform)
I have a chart that shows me information amount of entry log for a specific rule, using "Logs-based metrics".

The chart contains 2 labels: "Value" and "Name".
Value is amount the entry log.
Name is "information about log and names of resources"

My problems is, I do not understand why the chart is printing 2 differents lines (2 colors/rows).

Why there are 2 differentes lines color/rows if is the same rule? I see a differente value of date, but I do not understand it.
When the chart will generate a new serie (color/row)?

Follow the example below:

[image]

Edit:
Another Example
[image]

Comment: Because of different labels?

Comment: Yes @Nakilon, I do not understand why there are 2 labels, why was diveded in 2 series. When GCP will create a new serie?

Comment: Are you using default monitoring agent? I'm not sure how it works -- I send timeseries by myself via API. The "labels" property of a single record is exactly for splitting so you can have several lines in one chart. For example, for my Compute Engine I have a chart with a line for each application I run by making label equal to working directory of an app.

Comment: Oh sry, reread the question in post. I really don't know why that works in that way.

Comment: No problems @Nakilon.
My chart is about (GAE) and show about the an unique module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this case.
Each line references to each version of app.
In this case, this chart is about informations request for unique GAE module.
I saw that value "gae_app(2017...)" is the version that was deployed.

So, now I get it.

Thank you all for the attention